# RFB reference implementation?

Tags: network-programming, rfb-protocol

I'm writing an RFB server. I was wondering if anybody knows of an RFB reference client.

Currently, I run RealVNC and ask it to connect to my RFB server, and it works fine. However, RealVNC is intended to give a good end-user experience. It is *not* intended to test every possible valid combination of protocol features. So I know that the features which RealVNC uses are implemented correctly, but I have no idea whether the features that RealVNC doesn't use are working at all. But it would be really useful if I could check somehow.

Any suggestions?

(I could, of course, write my own RFB client as well. But that wouldn't really prove anything. If something doesn't work, I can't tell if it's the client or the server that's broken. And if everything does work, that *still* doesn't mean that both ends implement RFB correctly, just that each has the same bugs as the other.)

Answer (score 0):

This  may help you  out a bit. I use  to use TCP/IP builder to make various hexcode messages(pointer event, key event, cut text)  store  them in a text  file. Now  i Used to  connect the tcp/ip builder with my rfb/vnc server.

The RFB server  you wrote will now  respond to this  TCP/IP builder  like  any RFB Client  and  you can now  verify  each and  every  scenario (  incomplete payload, wrong message number, extra  payload, message  out of  sequence etc)

> Make  sure  you select "Parse Ascii" option  if  your  server  doesnt 
>   respond  with  rfb version number info  once  you  connect to  your
>   server.

In  order  to make the  the intial message  you can  record  wireshark logs  for a successful  proper  rfb  session  between  your  rfb server and  real vnc and  then  use those  messages  to  test  your  RFB server  with TCP/IP builder.

> The  RFB version  info can  be send  like this "RFB 003.008" , but 
>   for the  rest of the message  you  will have to  use hex symbol like
>   it is  seen  network logs (pcap/wireshark)
>
> example : this is  how to send  Framebuffer  request message to  your
>   server (non-incremental  for  800 x 480)
>
> 0x030x000x000x000x000x000x030x200x010xe0